# Spring Boot - creating Bean as Singleton in IOC container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ioc-container

Bean creation is supposed to be a Singleton in the spring container, correct?  I am migrating a Spring configuration file to Spring Boot with Annotations.  I have the below code, but it seems to call the "mySingletonBean()" every time that it is used within another bean creation.  It is my understanding that the @Bean annotation is supposed to be Singleton by default.  Am I creating my Beans correctly?

```
@Bean
public SomeBean mySingletonBean() {
  SomeBean mybean = new SomeBean();
  mybean.setName = "Name";
  return mybean;
}

@Bean 
public Bean1 bean1() {
  Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
  bean1.setBean(mySingletonBean());
  return bean1;
}

@Bean 
public Bean2 bean2() {
  Bean2 bean2 = new Bean2();
  bean2.setBean(mySingletonBean());
  return bean2;
}
```

Comment: The method call will be proxied in `@Configuration`. classes and result in the same instance. This does however only apply to `@Configuration` classes and not `@Component classes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Do you observe 2 different instances of `SomeBean` being created, or is it your worry that calling the method might/will lead to duplicate bean creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is proxying your application context class, and takes care of all the context related stuff like instantiating, caching etc. of the beans.

Run this small test, feel free to debug to see what class the configuration class became:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Test.MyContext.class)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myStringBean")
    private String myStringBean;
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @Configuration
    static class MyContext {

        @Bean
        public String myStringBean() {
            return String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
        }

        @Bean
        public SomeBean mySomeBean() {
            return new SomeBean(myStringBean());
        }

    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(myStringBean == applicationContext.getBean("myStringBean"));
        assertTrue(myStringBean == someBean.getValue());
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBean("myStringBean"), myStringBean, someBean.getValue()));
    }

    static class SomeBean {

        private String value;

        public SomeBean(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spring Boot is smart framework and method `mySingletonBean()` will starts only once time, don't worry about it. U can start debug mode and see .